# Testing SSO without IDP

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to set up an IDP-Initiated SSO. I am helping out the IT department at the company I work at and do not have access to Active Directory right now (I am in intern doing IT in another department and they seem to think I can test without it).

The only data I need to get from AD is the user's login id, so in theory I don't think not having access to AD will be a problem...?

(Username should be the same as .NET's:
`Environment.UserName; ')

My task is to basically create a SAML token and send it to our RP (on another domain), who should take care of the rest.

Where can I start? I've not done something like this, so I'm sort of confused. I believe I just need to build a token and then post it, but I'm not sure how to begin. I've looked at some tutorials but they don't seem to fit my situation. If anyone has any tutorials on my specific case it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: In case it helps, you CAN view AD objects using the RSAT tools. Install these, then type dsa.msc at a run prompt to fire up the familiar Active Directory Users and Computers. Might be useful if you need to see the object and OU structure visually as part of your planning. Link for RSAT: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this C# and .NET so looks like you live in the Microsoft world.

The normal way to do this is via ADFS and then configure your RP.

But you want to do IDP Initiated which is a SAML feature. What protocol does your RP support? There is no client-side Microsoft SAML support - although there are 3rd party tools.

**Update**

Suggest using ADFS - good example of how to configure [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-on_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I have to use Microsoft technologies and the service provider supports SAML 1.1 and 2.0, although I would prefer to use 2.0.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you say "SAML" are you talking about the SAML protocol or SAML tokens?

Comment: I'm referring to protocol.

Comment: OK - note that @Wiktor's comment about WIF refers to tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I wrote a 6 part tutorial on integrating a custom STS with the ADFS. Part 2 of that tutorial is on creating a custom STS.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/08/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web.html

Note that the tutorial aims at WIF 4 that was a separate download at that time. Nowadays, WIF is integrated with .NET 4.5 so that some subtle details (namespaces etc) can vary.

Also note that WIF supports SAML 1.1.